# How to pass field value into apex

Tags: apex, lightning

Hi I have a problem with passing parameter into apex class. I need to pass there field value from object. This value is hidden and its not showing anywhere in component, its only saved in database.

```
    deleteTemporaryTransaction : function(cmp, event){
        var action = cmp.get("c.deleteTempTransactions");
        cmp.set("v.data", []);
        action.setParams

//how to add value HERE
({klipId : *value here* });

        action.setCallback(this, function (actionResult) {

        })
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        console.log("delete temp");
    },
```

Comment: Can you explain more this:- I need to pass their field value from the object. This value is hidden and it is not showing anywhere in the component, its only saved in the database?

Comment: I have a object, where are many custom fields. I have an aura iterator which is showing me data. When i want to delete on button click, i need to pass specific value of one field there. For example i have field "CaseId__c" and i want to usite like this         `action.setParams

({klipId :  {!data.CaseId__c });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the argument value in your apex controller through Client side controller as follows:-

```
({
    handClick : function(component, event, helper) {

         var ObjectWith5Fields = component.get("v.candidate");
        var action = component.get("c.saveRecord");
        action.setParams({
            "cand" : ObjectWith5Fields
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if( state === "SUCCESS") {
                alert("hello from here");
            }
        } );
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Here, I am getting the Object value using

**var ObjectWith5Fields = component.get("v.candidate");**

and then calling the apex method as:-

**var action = component.get("c.saveRecord");**

and setting the value of argument using

**action.setParams({
            "cand" : ObjectWith5Fields
        });**

And, Here is my apex Controller:-

```
public with sharing class SampleAppController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void saveRecord(Candidate__c cand){
        if(cand!= null){
            insert cand;
        }
        System.debug('candidate is-->>' + cand);

    }
}
```

If you want to use it like this `action.setParams ({klipId : {!data.CaseId__c });`

After getting the object value from Component, what you need is set as follows:-

```
action.setParams({
            "klipId " : ObjectWith5Fields.CaseId__c 
        });
```

here ObjectWith5Fields is the variable to store the object value, as you can see in Controller code.

Comment: Hi thanks for tip, i used it like this `deleteTemporaryTransaction : function(cmp){
        var claimedTransData = cmp.get("v.data");
        var action = cmp.get("c.deleteTempTransactions");
        action.setParams(
            {"klipId" : claimedTransData.KLIP_Subcase}
        );
        console.log(claimedTransData.KLIP_Subcase__c);
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        console.log("delete temp");
    }` but its still "undefined"

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: no, its still passing undefined value

Comment: Update your question with what you are actually trying to achieve and component code snippet. I want to look at that and then suggest you.

Comment: No its working fine now, your answer was useful. I had a typo in code.

Comment: Ohh finally. Welcome :) @David